# Google Drive multipart upload return badContent in PHP Curl

Tags: php, post, file-upload, google-drive-api, php-curl

I give up. I am able to make a media upload (2 steps) but I am unable to implement a multipart upload to Google Drive without boundary logic. No matter what I have tried it keep returning badContent with the [message] => Unsupported content with type: application/octet-stream.
So in my view it looks as if it is unable to find the mime type (it is wrong) or unable to find the file in the post. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 public function uploadFileToGoogleDriveMulti($accessToken, $filePath, $fileType, $fileName, $folderID)
{
    /*
    trigger_error("DEBUG: ".print_r($accessToken, true));
    trigger_error("DEBUG: ".print_r($filePath, true));
    trigger_error("DEBUG: ".print_r($fileType, true));
    trigger_error("DEBUG: ".print_r($fileName, true));
    trigger_error("DEBUG: ".print_r($folderID, true));
    */

    $cFile = curl_file_create($filePath, $fileType, $fileName);  
    //trigger_error("DEBUG: ".print_r($cFile, true));        

    $curl = curl_init();
   
    $postdata = array
    (
      'metadata' => json_encode
      (array
        (
          'name' => $fileName,
          //'parents' => array($folderID),
          //'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' 
        )
      ),
      //'file' => new CURLFILE($filePath, $fileType),
      //'file_contents'=> $cFile
      'file' => $cFile,
      //'Content-Type' => $fileType . '\n\n' . file_get_contents($filePath)                   
    );
            
    $headers = array
    (
      'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
      //'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
      'Content-Type: multipart/related',
      //'Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen(serialize($postdata), '8bit')
    );

    $post_string = json_encode($data);  

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, Config::GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_UPLOAD_URI . '?uploadType=multipart');
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $curlResponse = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    trigger_error("DEBUG: ".print_r($curlResponse, true));

    if ($responseCode != 200) 
    {
        $errorMessage = 'Failed to upload file to drive';
        if(curl_errno($curl)) 
        {
            $errorMessage = curl_error($curl);
        }
        throw new Exception('Error ' . $responseCode . ': ' . $errorMessage);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $curlResponse['id'];
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. From `but I am unable to implement a multipart upload to Google Drive without boundary logic.`, you want to achieve `multipart/related` request for uploading content of Drive API without `boundary logic` using curl of PHP?

Comment: My expected result is that the file is uploaded to Google Drive. Right now Google return an error code because of a mismatch between the file and the mime type (as far as I understand it). I just like to use some code without the need to make a header that have boundary=xxxxxx

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I just like to use some code without the need to make a header that have boundary=xxxxxx`, I understood that you wanted to upload a file to Google Drive with `multipart/related` without `boundary logic` using php curl. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct.

Comment: Why don't you want to set the boundary? According to the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#http_1) and the [RFC 2046 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1) this is mandatory in all `multipart` uploads.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. Did not know that. Will try to implement it with boundary. Just think it is a strange syntax....